# Django Admin not limiting choices on ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I suddenly am having a problem with my django admin panel.

I have the following models:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=32)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=64)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role)

class Team(models.Model):
    rep = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name="rep_on",
        limit_choices_to={'role__name': 'Sales Rep'})
    eng = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name="eng_on",
        limit_choices_to={'role_id__name': "Engineer"})
```

(The two options in the `limit_choices_to` dictionaries are the two methods I've tried. In the past it seemed like `role_id__name` worked, but now it doesn't.)

If I create roles for the Sales Rep and Engineer, and create a bunch of people and attach roles, when I create a Team in the admin, I get dropdowns like I expect:

[image: Admin screen adding two lists of related objects]

There are two problems. Each dropdown contains every Person object, so `limit_choices_to` doesn't seem to work at all, and of course these relationships are generic "TEAM-PERSON RELATIONSHIPS" and I'd like to be able to at least label those correctly.

I swear this worked before, and now it's not working. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

EDIT:

I created a [toy application](https://github.com/JoshuaEnglish/djangotest) to explore this and tried to slowly recreate the full issue. In my real app I am using two Inlines in the admin interface for the Team object and excluding the model fields. I added them into my test code and managed to recreate the issue.

```
class RepInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Team.rep.through


class EngInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Team.eng.through


class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [RepInline, EngInline]

admin.site.register(Role)
admin.site.register(Person)
admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

And my admin screen looks like:
[image]

The given HTML Select fields are filtered, but the dropdowns are not, So the issue lies in the TabularInline, so I have to decide if I want to keep them or not.

Comment: Hmm I can't replicate the error. Both the `role__name` and `role_id__name` methods work for me for `limit_choices_to`. In Django Admin when I "Add team" I have two multiple select menus with the correct `Person` objects (based on role) and they're labelled "Rep" and "Eng" respectively.

Comment: Assuming that the issue may not lie in the model definition, perhaps something has changed in admin.py? Could you share the code here?